# How can I deactivate Asset Versioning in Magnolia 5.7

Tags: assets, jcr, magnolia

We have a massive problem regarding assets (images) in our magnolia 5.7 system.

I can describe it like this:

1. On our author server we create a completely new asset.
2. When we publish that asset and look at it on our public server we see that it has the mixinTypes "mgnl:hasVersion" and the link to the image (That is inserted and worked on our author server) is not working anymore.

Do you know what could be the cause of this and how can I deactivate that automatic versioning of images?

UPDATE:

We have managed to fix the broken links problem with using the recovery-flag from here: https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/Administration/Troubleshooting/Broken-version-history.html

Still we have versioning on our public server. Here is the diff between the two xml-exports of the asset-nodes:

```
<     <sv:value>mix:versionable</sv:value>
13,24d11
<   <sv:property sv:name="jcr:baseVersion" sv:type="Reference">
<     <sv:value>55f158e2-16c7-44ce-a973-cd48a5cad53b</sv:value>
<   </sv:property>
<   <sv:property sv:name="jcr:isCheckedOut" sv:type="Boolean">
<     <sv:value>true</sv:value>
<   </sv:property>
<   <sv:property sv:name="jcr:predecessors" sv:type="Reference" sv:multiple="true">
<     <sv:value>55f158e2-16c7-44ce-a973-cd48a5cad53b</sv:value>
<   </sv:property>
<   <sv:property sv:name="jcr:versionHistory" sv:type="Reference">
<     <sv:value>e1dfbbf9-e9be-468d-a20c-11c2cb978aa4</sv:value>
<   </sv:property>
31,33d17
<   <sv:property sv:name="mgnl:comment" sv:type="String">
<     <sv:value/>
<   </sv:property>
41c25
<     <sv:value>2021-03-03T10:42:37.277+01:00</sv:value>
---
>     <sv:value>2021-03-03T10:47:35.533+01:00</sv:value>
45a30,35
>   <sv:property sv:name="mgnl:lastActivatedVersion" sv:type="String">
>     <sv:value>jcr:frozenNode</sv:value>
>   </sv:property>
>   <sv:property sv:name="mgnl:lastActivatedVersionCreated" sv:type="Date">
>     <sv:value>2021-03-03T10:47:35.139+01:00</sv:value>
>   </sv:property>
93c83
<       <sv:value>2021-03-03T10:42:37.278+01:00</sv:value>
---
>       <sv:value>2021-03-03T10:47:35.539+01:00</sv:value>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find it under the node type definition, must be named such as this: magnolia-dam-nodetypes.xml

If you remove `<supertype>mgnl:versionable</supertype>` from the definition, it should not version the nodes anymore.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Where should this file be located? I could just find custom_nodetypes.xml in /data/author/repositories/magnolia/repository/nodetypes/ Should I just try to throw it there? Do you know why this could appear without having changed something knowingly?

Comment: It should be under DAM module -> https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/MODULES/repos/dam

Comment: why would versioning break images? Are you sure that if you remove the mixin, link will be working again? Isn't that caused by something else? Is actual asset binary published? what diff do you see if you export published asset from author and from public?

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for also jumping in. I updated my Question with the diff.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with decorations to override and remove `catalog: versioned` from publish action.
Original actions:
https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/MODULES/repos/dam/browse/magnolia-dam-app-jcr/src/main/resources/dam-app-jcr/decorations/dam-assets-app/apps/dam.subApps.yaml

/your module name/decorations/dam-assets-app/apps/dam.subApps.yaml

```
jcrBrowser:
  actions:
    publish: !override
      icon: icon-publish
      class: info.magnolia.ui.contentapp.action.JcrCommandActionDefinition
      command: publish
      availability: *notDeletedWritableAvailability
```